# What about high answer quality?

Tags: discussion

There has been a large amount of warning about making sure we get started with high quality questions, but what about high quality answers?

I think so far the answers we have been getting are just ok but not great. They may be factually correct, but I don't think they do a great job at *explaining*.

Is this something we need to be worried about? On electronics.SE we are just starting to get higher quality answers and I have noticed it has started to cause others to increase their answer quality as well. I think setting the tone here that we expect high quality answer is critical, but I want to know what others think.

Answer (score 7):

If you see an answer that could be improved, edit it! If you simply have a *better* answer to offer; well, we all love to show off a bit on occasion. Post a better answer!

That goes to *everybody* on this system, of course.

A big part of this process is *actively* building the best possible canonical answers to these questions… collectively. More users are coming next week, but right now, you are part of that process. It's time to make this site a place where experts will want to hang out. So, go ahead and fix the answers you see as lacking or go ahead and add better ones.

The first answers received are not necessarily the *best* answers (or even *correct* answers); That's what the voting is for. If you like an answer, vote it up! If you don't find it particularly insightful, don't vote for it. If it is unhelpful or simply wrong, vote it down. That way the best answers will rise to the top.

#### Why we obsess over quality *questions*

At this earliest stage, we obsess over the quality of the *questions* because the questions that appear on your home page are going to tell potential experts a *lot* about your site. It is, essentially, your design.

But you're right. The quality of the *answers* is just as important. But they're coming.

Next week we are going to open the front doors to this site (public beta). When experts come across  your site, you want them to see very interesting and challenging questions, not the basic questions found on every other forum on the Internet. You want them say "Wow, this is the site for me!" Remember, the pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around! That is why it is so important to get awesome questions in these opening days.

See the blog post: [**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

And don't forget to vote on the best content. That's how you reward users for their contribution and make sure the *best* answers float to the top of the stack!

Answer (score 6):

I fully support you in this. This site has great potential to be a good resource for signal processing questions, both theoretical and practical and good answers are critical for its success.

In the initial stages, everyone tries to answer everything with the hope of a few easy rep points because private beta + first few days of public beta is when the most upvotes are given out. Also, some people are overly concerned about Area51 stats like answers/question etc and try to bulk it up.

We should actively discourage this by downvoting meagre or marginal content and encouraging the user to add in answers of value.